# Slack API to re-create Google Drive "attachment" integration from bot

Tags: python, google-drive-api, slack, slack-api

**Background**

I've created a slack bot that listens in a channel for when a file is uploaded, downloads the content and re-uploads it to our Google Drive account and deletes it from Slack.  This all works perfectly using slack-client api and google drive api in `Python`.

**Problem**

What I would like to recreate is the view that the Google Drive slack integration creates when you import a file from Google Drive, instead of just having a link (like my bot current [is capable of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5e3UV.png)).

I'm currently using `slack_client.api_call("chat.postMessage", ..., unfurl_media=True, unfurl_links=True)` however, that does not solve the problem (it still just appears as a link as seen above, instead of an attachment like the [Google Drive integration.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDN5f.png))

Anyone have any recomendations on how to achieve the same look at the Google Drive integration?  The idea is that the thumbnails and previews of attachments should not go away, but everything should be hosted on Google Drive as opposed to Slack's servers since we share a **ton** of files.

Comment: were you able to resolve this Aphit?

Comment: @user9063834 I was not able to resolve this and ultimately gave up on the effort